# How can I easily add code under the <body> tag without using hooks?

Tags: plugins, code

I need to trying to get the Facebook SDK for JavaScript code inserted just after the  tag.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your theme files (probably header.php), you will find starting `<body>` tag. Just paste the code below it.

Comment: How to make this persist across theme updates?

Comment: In that case, you need to create a Child theme. See here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to modify your theme's template, or use the ghastly approach of stuffing it into the DOM with jQuery.

They just do not yet have a hook for things like this.  It is being discussed...

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21506